# Select a row in TableViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

I have a `TableViewer` in my application that has the following features:

- It gets data from a web service, and upon selecting a row, buttons get enabled and you can make operations (all these operations are calling the webservice, so the table stays in sync with the database).
- When I add a new line, I submit an "add" command to the web service, and refresh the table. Now I have a new line, and I know which line is the new one.

Now I want to select the new line by default, and I tried many commands like `tableViewer.getTable().select(index);` and as it is now:

```
public void selectAdded(int id) {
    tableViewer.getTable().setSelection(id);
}
```

This picture shows what is the problem: [image: The two different type of selections]

The upper one shows as it works now with this code. The row below shows how it looks when I click a row. The problem is, the buttons don't get enabled, and I have two read-only text fields that remains blank instead of showing the information I need. But when I click, everything works normally.

What should I do to achive that `selectAdded(int id)` acts like a click? The solution should be multi-platform (Mac/Windows), but at least on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `Table` selection methods which using `TableViewer`. Instead use

```
ISelection selection = new StructuredSelection(model object);

tableViewer.setSelection(selection);
```

'model object' is the model object for the row you want to select (as returned by your content provider).

Comment: Thank you, it's working. My boss noticed that it would be better if the selection is shown  by blue color (now it's dark grey). Any idea?

Comment: On most platforms dark blue is used when the control (table) has focus, dark grey when something else has focus. Changing the focus color is difficult.

Comment: Thank you very much! I add `tableViewer.getTable().setFocus();` and it's perfectly look like I wanted.